# map containing std::function<T()> and std::function<T(int)>

Tags: c++, dictionary, c++11, stdmap, std-function

I'd like to have a single map that maps string keys to either a `std::function<T()>` or `std::function<T(int)>` (but not both for a given key). I get a compile error that there doesn't seem to be a template for `std::function<T(...)>`. I'd like to be able to use lambdas as the values.

First, is it *safe* to store functions this way? Second, if so, what would the syntax be? (Whether the function was unary or nullary would be known when it's retrieved from the map.) And if none-of-the-above, what would be a reasonable alternative? Pointers kills the lambda idea, right…

C++11 is OK.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, that's one way out! At some point, I'd like to be able to hide this, e.g., only one get method on the class with the map. But I can certainly work around it.

Comment: Why not just have two containers? Since you'll have to do some checking anyway so you know how to *call* the function, you might as well do the checking by separating the two types of functions.

Answer (score 5):

One alternative is to wrap the nullary functions in a wrapper lambda that takes one argument, does nothing with it, and simply calls the wrapped function.  Then everything in your map is a unary function.

Of course, if you know at retrieval time what type the function is (which I guess you have to, otherwise it's useless!), then why not just use two maps?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try `boost::variant`?

```
std::map<std::string, boost::variant<std::function<T()>, std::function<T(int)> > >
```

Anyway, this seems like an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/181277). What *exactly* are you trying to do?

Comment: I'd like a Factory pattern where the "stamper" objects (object creators) are either nullary or unary, and the map is keyed by class name or the equivalent names in the problem domain. I can use std::bind on the unary ones to turn them into nullary before the final objects are created.

Answer (score 2):

Empty `std::function` are not that heavy.  You could just map to a struct containing one of each.  You know which is valid, so only access that one.

If you have template code that needs to operate on both uniformly without being passed in either as an argument:

```
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <map>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

template<typename T>
using my_maps = std::tuple< std::map<std::string, std::function<T()>>, std::map<std::string, std::function<T(int)>>>;


int main() {
  my_maps<double> maps;
  std::get<0>(maps)["pi"] = [](){ return 3.14; };
  std::get<1>(maps)["e^"] = [](int x){ return pow( 2.7, x ); };
  std::cout << std::get<1>(maps)["e^"](2) << "\n";
  std::cout << std::get<0>(maps)["pi"]() << "\n";
}
```

This has two maps, with the difference in access a `get<0>` or a `get<1>`.  This has the advantage that if you are picking which of the two to access in a template, it can pick 0 or 1 statically and use common code.  If you don't need this, just have two `std::map`s.

A `boost::variant` also works (map to a `variant` of either a 0ary or 1ary function).  You can also use a C++11 `union` (with the note that it will have no default constructor, or copy constructor, unless you supply one) in a `struct` with an enum (which does the copy of the `union`) -- basically a ghetto `boost::variant`.